# Yii2 query with where and or

Tags: yii2

I'm struggling with this one, I've tried allsorts of combinations and nothing comes up with what I want.
So my sql code is

```
select * from table where organisation_id`= org_id 
AND due_at` <= start_date 
AND due_at` >= end_date 
AND category_id = cat_id
and ((standard_task_template_id is null) or (standard_task_template_id not in (standardQuery))
```

and my yii2 code is

```
$query = TaskEventAllocation::find()
->where([TaskEventAllocation::tableName().'.organisation_id'=> $organisation_id])
           ->andWhere(['<=','due_at', $unix_end_date->getTimestamp()])
        ->andWhere(['>=', 'due_at', $unix_start_date->getTimestamp()])
$query->andWhere(['tc.id' => $cat_or_group_id]);
```

then if I add

```
$query->andWhere('and',['is', 'standard_task_template_id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')],['or', ['not in', 'standard_task_template_id', $standardTaskIds]]);
```

it returns

```
SELECT `t_task_event_allocation`.* 
FROM `t_task_event_allocation` 
 WHERE (`t_task_event_allocation`.`organisation_id`=:qp3) 
AND (`due_at` <= :qp4) 
AND (`due_at` >= :qp5) 
AND (`group_id` != :qp6) A
ND (`tc`.`id`=:qp7) 
AND (and)
```

I've tried

```
$query->andWhere('or',['is', 'standard_task_template_id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')],['and', ['not in', 'standard_task_template_id', $standardTaskIds]]);
```

that produces the same as above but with in an or in brackets

```
$query->andWhere(['is', 'standard_task_template_id', new \yii\db\Expression('null')], 'or', ['not in', 'standard_task_template_id', $standardTaskIds]);
```

produces an error saying argument 2 must be of the type array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
->andWhere([
    'or',
    ['standard_task_template_id' => null],
    ['not in', 'standard_task_template_id', $standardTaskIds]
]);
```

Comment: @HelenPostle If you found this answer useful and want to say thanks, do it by [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or voting on it. See in the help pages why [voting is important](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).